# How to pass a function reference to a child component while also using the state of the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm not sure exactly how to word this, so I'll do some pseudo code to illustrate:

I have a main component that has a map function that is iterating over an array of values. Inside the map function is a functional prop that references a handler function. I want to be able to not only return a value from the onClick, but I need to access variables that are still inside the mapped instance of the component.

```
parent
[1,2,3].map(num => ( <child funcProp={handleClick} )

in child:
const {funcProp} = props
---code that does calc or state
funcProp(res)
```

I'm getting the result I want from the child component, but I need a parameter from the invoking map as well. So for instance, I'd want (if we're at number 2 in the map) I want to return the res from the child component *with* the `num` 2 for the handler function. I'm sure there's some syntax that I am forgetting.

Comment: The simpliest way is to pass a new anonymous function `funcProp={(child_args) => handleClick(num, child_args)}`.

Comment: Oh my gosh! I wasn't including it in the anonymous function! I think that's where I went wrong! It works. Wow - What a derp moment. :/

Answer (score 1):

The rules of closures still apply in React. Create an anonymous function that calls `handleClick` itself. This function will have access to the map callback arguments:

```
[1,2,3].map((num) => {
  return <child funcProp={() => handleClick(num)} />
})
```

Note that with this pattern, `handleClick` will no longer receive arguments from a call to `funcProp` in the `child` component. If you still want `handleClick` to receive these arguments, you must pass them along explicitly:

```
[1,2,3].map((num) => {
  return <child funcProp={(...args) => handleClick(num, ...args)} />
})
```

Or, if you want `num` to be the last argument to `handleClick`:

```
[1,2,3].map((num) => {
  return <child funcProp={(...args) => handleClick(...args.concat(num))} />
})
```

You could avoid the anonymous function though, and make use of `Function.prototype.bind` to create a bound copy of `handleClick` with a fixed first argument of `num`:

```
[1,2,3].map((num) => {
  return <child funcProp={handleClick.bind(null, num)} />
})
```

In this case, we bind `handleClick` to the context `null`. This may or may not be appropriate for your use case - something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will let you access the value you want

```
[1,2,3].map(num => ( <child funcProp={() => handleClick(num)} )
```

Or pass the value in the child props as well

```
[1,2,3].map(num => ( <child num={num} funcProp={handleClick} )
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you might need to binding with "this" while passing the function.

If i use the example you mentioned then maybe this could help -

```
handleClick.bind(this)
```